# VB2010 String adds up Length by adding ""

Tags: vb.net, string, char, indexof

I'am comparing `Strings` in Visual Basic 2010 Express. While cuting the `String` together it sometimes adds a `Char` with `""`, what I hoped is "nothing"

Example:

```
Dim text as String = "test"
Dim sign as Char = ""
text = text + sign
```

while debuging it says that the new text is `"test"`, but if I ask for the `Length` it is 5.

This is a problem when I try to compare this with an other `String`

```
Dim bigtext as String = "test1234"
Dim text as String = "test"
Dim sign as Char = ""
text = text + sign
bigtext.indexOf(text) 'should be 0 (index), but is -1 (not found)
```

any idea how to filter a `""` away or any other workaround?

---

Edit - my workoround for now:

Now I add `"§"` everywhere instead of `""` and when I need to use `indexOf()` to compare something, I `Replace("§", "")` it. 
(with `Replace()` it is deleted)

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-empty-vbnet can't reproduce it, though

Comment: @Fᴀʀʜᴀɴ Aɴᴀᴍ what I need is more something like a `Char.Empty`

Comment: Probably related to the fact that in C#, you can't have an empty character literal... VB is weird with how it works so probably enforces this by making it a `\0` under the hood

Comment: Turn Option Strict On and use & for concatenation in VB not +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, a `Char` variable always has a character in it (which can be the null character). Concatenating it to another string will append that character to the existing string.

I see two workarounds:

1. Use a String for `sign` instead of a Char. The string could be empty or have a single character in it.
2. Trim the undesired character from the resulting string:

   `text = (text + sign).Trim(CChar(""))`

Comment: @ConnersFan I used the second part succesfully. Using Strings was not possible for me. I edited my solution to the bottom of the question - just used an unused char